# Solving eigen problem with sparse matrices?

Tags: opencv, matrix, eigen, sparse-matrix, eigenvector

I'm trying to compute the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a fairly big matrix. I expect that matrix will be sparse though. Can anyone recommend a way to solve this efficiently?

I've called cv::eigen but the process takes way too long. If anyone has an efficient implementation or a library to solve this I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: have you looked into [this thread](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/351/recommendations-for-a-usable-fast-c-matrix-library)?

Comment: @Shai I did. I found that most (even Eigen!) don't have eigen decomposition with sparse matrices. I'm looking into Suitesparse and ARPACK, but I was trying to probe and see if there's any consensus for this in the community. Thanks for the pointer!